# Pygame breaks outside of Pydev.

Tags: python, pygame

Me and a team of friends created this game which I am now trying to run in linux,

We developed it using python 2.7 and Pygame in windows using Aptana studio and the code fully work when running through there.

When downloading it to linux It wouldn't load saying that it could not find files. I then tried running it via CMD in windows and there is the same error.

the error so far is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Raspberroids/mainmenu.py", line 144, in <module>
    showMenu()
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Raspberroids/mainmenu.py", line 107, in showMenu
    menu.init(['Start','About','Quit'], surface)
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Raspberroids/mainmenu.py", line 52, in init
    self.create_strukture()        
  File "/home/user/Desktop/Raspberroids/mainmenu.py", line 73, in create_strukture
    self.font = pygame.font.Font(self.font_path, self.fontsize)
IOError: unable to read font filename
```

And the source is at:
https://github.com/ryanteck/RasPiThon/tree/master/Raspberroids/Source%20Code

Happens on both 2.7 and 2.6

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your font path `data/coders_crux/coders_crux.ttf` is relative.

When you start your game from another directory than your source directory, pygame can't find the font.

---

A simple fix is to add the following lines to the top of your script (*mainmenu.py*):

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

[`os.path.realpath(\__file__)`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.realpath) will get the path to your script, and with [`os.chdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.chdir) and [`os.path.dirname`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname) you change the current working directory to the directory of your script.

This way, the relative paths you use will work.

Answer (score 1):

PyDev sets working directory and `PYTHONPATH` variable for your programs. It can also set console encoding to something different than OS defaults.

Add a `print self.font_path` statement before creating your Font object and see if path is OK. If it's relative path, you could also use `os.path.abspath` (see [os.path](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) docs for details) to get better understanding of what's going on.